# How a for loop works in Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have a code for calculating Fibonacci Sequence as shown below .. I do not understand how the for loop works in this example :

```
public class program {          
    private static int fibo (int n){
        if (n==1 || n==2) return 1;

        int f = 0;
        int f1 = 1;
        int f2 = 1;
        for (int i = 3; i <= n;i++) {
            f = f1 + f2;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f;
        }
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=7;
        System.out.println(fibo(n));
    }
}
```

The output of the code is `13`..

Comment: If you step through the code in your debugger (its the button next to run in your IDE) you can see exact what each line of code does and what each variable's value is.  You IDE also has a code formatter which I suggest you use.

Comment: @Ali12 please hit the upvote button if my answer helped you :D THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first two Fibonacci number are always `0` and `1`.
After that all following numbers are the sum of the previous two numbers.
According this the next step is `0 + 1 = 1`, which is the same as your code here:

```
int f = 0; //fibonacci #1
int f1 = 1; //fibonacci #2
int f2 = 1; //fibonacci #3
```

After that it wil loop through all numbers doing it the same way:

```
for (int i = 3;i <= n;i++) {
    //calculate the new fibanacci, will get the fibonacci #1 variable
    f = f1 + f2;

    //the next fibonacci #2 will be the same as fibonacci #3 was before
    f1 = f2;

    //set the new fibonacci to fibonacci #3
    f2 = f; 
}
```

When it finished looping, it just returns the fibonacci number:

```
return f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simpler value. Let's say `fibo` is called with `3`. It isn't `1` or `2`, so `f1`, `f2` and `f` are initialised (bad naming conventions, though). `i` starts at `3`, and `3 <= 3`, so `f` is initialised to `f1 + f2`, which is `2` (`1 + 1`). This is the third number of the Fibonacci sequence. Say `n` is `4`. The process is the same, however instead of halting due to `i` becoming `4` (`4 <= 3` is `false`), the code runs with `i = 4`, as `4 <= 4`. `f` (which is `2`) is assigned to `f1 + f2` again. `f1` was assigned to the previous value of `f2` (`1`), and `f2` was assigned to `f` (`2`). `f1 + f2 == 1 + 2 == 3`, so `f` becomes `3`, which is indeed the fourth Fibonacci number.

This process continues in the same way for higher values.